# Linker error using library built with VS2005 in VS2012 Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005, linker-errors

I am trying to build a library in VS2005. It was developed using VS2012 and in VS2012 everything works correctly, unfortunately, we need to provide the library with the VS2005 project (I used CMake  to generate both projects). I am able to build it with VS2005, but the moment that I try to link it, I get multiple linker errors (Mostly LNK2001 and LNK2019).

When I generate the VS2005 library and link it to a VS2012 test application (both define Runtime MDd) for debugging, I get these errors:

```
Error   26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall std::vector<class Class1 *,class std::allocator<class Class1 *> >::_Tidy(void)" (?_Tidy@?$vector@PAVClass1@@V?$allocator@PAVClass1@@@std@@@std@@IAEXXZ) C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class2.obj)   Test-Name
Error   20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::logic_error::logic_error(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0logic_error@std@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@@Z) C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class3.obj)   Test-Name
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned short,class Class5 *,struct std::less<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned short const ,class Class5 *> >,0>::~_Tmap_traits<unsigned short,class Class5 *,struct std::less<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned short const ,class Class5 *> >,0>(void)" (??1?$_Tmap_traits@GPAVClass5@@U?$less@G@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBGPAVClass5@@@std@@@3@$0A@@std@@QAE@XZ)   C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class3.obj)   Test-Name
Error   23  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned short,class Class5 *,struct std::less<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned short const ,class Class5 *> >,0>::_Tmap_traits<unsigned short,class Class5 *,struct std::less<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned short const ,class Class5 *> >,0>(struct std::less<unsigned short>)" (??0?$_Tmap_traits@GPAVClass5@@U?$less@G@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBGPAVClass5@@@std@@@3@$0A@@std@@QAE@U?$less@G@1@@Z) C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class3.obj)   Test-Name
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)  C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class2.obj)   Test-Name
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)  C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class4.obj)   Test-Name
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)    C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class2.obj)   Test-Name
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)    C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class4.obj)   Test-Name
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ) C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class2.obj)   Test-Name
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ) C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibraryd.lib(Class4.obj)   Test-Name
```

When I generate the VS2005 library and link it to a VS2012 test application (both define Runtime MD) for release, I get these errors:

```
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)  C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibrary.lib(Class3.obj)    Test-Name
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)  C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibrary.lib(Class2.obj)    Test-Name
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)  C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test-Name\Test-Name\testLibrary.lib(Class4.obj)    Test-Name
```

For the record, I have consulted google about these issues, some possible reasons encountered were:

1. Some class definitions are missing - This is not the case because when I test the Library built in VS2005 in a test application also created in VS2005, I am able to use it and debug it without problems.
2. Using strings - I do not use string at all on my project, not even the string header is defined. At most I use only maps.
3. Solve building with the same compiler as the test application https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8042a534-aa8b-4f99-81ee-e5ff39ae6e69/lnk2001-lnk2019-link-static-libraries-build-with-vs2005-with-vs2008?forum=vcgeneral - Unfortunately, the requirements we have is that it must be done with VS2005.
4. Use MT and MTd - Another of our requirements, is that we need to provide the library in all the Runtimes and even using MT and MTd causes linker errors.
5. Ignoring the default libraries in the application's properties - I do not ignore the default libraries.

I would really appreciate any feedback that you could provide regarding this problem. I find it very curious that it seems most of the errors are regarding strings when I don't use any.

Comment: Are you really required to use VS20**0**5 or is it a typo and you mean VS20**1**5?

Comment: This - "When I generate the VS2005 library and link it to a VS2012 test application" will never work.  MS has no ABI compatibility between versions.  You need to make individual builds for each version.  A C only interface (not C++) is supported at the ABI level between VS compiler versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a typo. It has to be 2005.

Comment: @RichardCritten I thought so too, but unfortunately one of my colleagues was able to create one library in VS2005 and we are able to link it without problems in a VS2012 project, thus I am required to do the same for this library.

Comment: @cyntia  the C++ runtime library (and template library) structures have changed between 2005 and 2012.  So when you pass a std::vector or std::string between the two modules you will get memory corruption.  If you stick to a C only interface and are careful about memory management it will work.

Comment: @RichardCritten, I will try to do that. I will look more into detail to the implementation of my colleague and see where how he defined the wrapper (unfortunately it is a very big implementation). Thank you so much for your help and quick response.